# iPhone Native Stocks Application

Tags: iphone, yahoo, finance

Anyone know how apple uses yahoo finance api to get the historical data for stocks at different times of the dat. Also, how to get the quote price for a given stock at different times of the day for today instead of just the current quote?

It seems that the yahoo finance api can be used to get the current price, and the iChart.yahoo.. can be used to get closing prices for stocks each day. Thanks!

Josh

Comment: Maybe they have a special contract allowing them access to more data? Maybe they are paying for that...

Comment: Or maybe apple cache the data on their own servers ? One could technically snap the data every X seconds to keep an intraday history.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Mergent Historical Securities Data API - http://www.mergent.com/servius